# google spreadsheet script changes comma to full-stop upon reading from a cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

So, I'm trying to read data from a cell in Google Spreadsheet's script and something's not right for me. I made a quick test function that takes the data from the cell, turns it to a string and returns the result, like so:

```
function TEST(str)
{
  return str.toString();
}
```

Then I made two test cells:

```
A1 with "17"
A2 with "135,136"
A3 with "1,11,29,43,68,74,109,122"
```

Then I called my function and I'm baffled by results

```
TEST(A1) returns "17"
TEST(A2) returns "135.136"
TEST(A3) returns "1,11,29,43,68,74,109,122"
```

So it seems that if there is exactly one comma it gets cast to a full-stop instead but if there are multiple none of them get replaced. What is going on and how can I read data from a cell as a string with 100% certainty that it won't get changed in any way?

Comment: Try changing the format of column A.

Comment: Is your Spreadsheet set for some european country where a comma represents a decimal seperator?  In that case A2 is correct, but with multiple commas it is already a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Some locations use `,` as decimal separator. So, `135,136` is a valid number(=`135.136`). But, `1,11,29,43,68,74,109,122` is not. Valid numbers are by default aligned to the right of the cell(Clear cell formatting to witness).

#### Solution(s):

- Set your locale properly, if you're going to use `,`s as commas and not as decimal separators OR
- Input numbers as text. Use `'` before inputting data in each cell. `'135,136` OR
- Send inputs as Text. `=TEST(TO_TEXT(A1))` OR
- Use `range#getDisplayValues()` instead.

Comment: Well, using apostrophe fixed the issue. What is weird is that it fixes it even for other cells where I didn't use it that had two numbers too (I added a new column with "46,47" and it didn't get changed to a full-stop). It's weird but now I know where the issue is, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The A Column where this data is stored, it's format should be changed and that would solve the issue.
**Select A Column** --> **Format** --> **Number** -- **Plain Text**. Changing the format will serve the purpose.

Hope it could help!.

Comment: That's useful to know, though I'd never look for text formatting under 'number' :) However, I checked it and I already have Plain Text selected. Still, good to know, thank you!