# force setFormula() to use , instead of . as decimal sign

Tags: google-apps-script, decimal, locale

I am using Apps script to create different data-sets from csv files.
I have a "master sheet" where I have all my meta-data so I can filter out specific traits that I want to analyse. I also have a place where I can paste formulas for threshold values for specific parameters.
So the process flow is:

- select criterias/traits on one sheet and run a script.
- that script looks through a database with all the traits and picks out the relevant csv files, kind of like a filter.
- the chosen parameter values are then extracted from the csv files and pasted into a new spreadsheet where the first sheet is a master sheet containing the traits and the formulas for the thresholds. a new sheet is then created for each parameter and the data is pasted into this sheet with a ID to each csv file in the left most column and that files parameter data in the same row.
- The script then inserts new columns between the ID and the data in which I paste the relevant threshold formulas for that parameter.
- Some formulas contain placeholder values like {a} which before I paste, exchange for a cell reference before posting with "setFormula()"

**Problem**
This works pretty well but the main issue I am having right now is that some thresholds are static and not dependent on other values so instead of a formula it is just a value, say 0,4.
So on my "master sheet" I have one parameter who has the threshold "0,4" but when it gets put through the script it comes out as "=0.4" with a DOT instead of COMMA as decimal sign. Since I am using the swedish Locale, sheets are not able to parse the formula. I have de-bugged it and noticed that is already when apps script gets the values through getRange().getValues() that the DOT appears instead of COMMA.
And the funny thing is that when I have a formula it correctly parse the COMMA as the decimal sign.

**Question**
Why does this happen and is there an easy way to get the output with the correct decimal sign?

**CODE for importing threshold formulas.**

```
 var ssNewId = Drive.Files.insert(resource);
  var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssNewId.id);
  var threshholdFormulas = ss.getSheetByName("Acceptance levels").getRange("A1:E19").getValues(); //In this line the formulas are read and its also here that the . appears
  var thresholdstoPush =  [];
  for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
    var index = parameters[i][1]+1;
    if (index >= 0 && index < threshholdFormulas.length) {
      thresholdstoPush.push(threshholdFormulas[index]);
    }
  }
  const thObj = arrayToNestedObject(threshholdFormulas);
```

```
function copyAndReplaceFormulas(thObj, placeholderObj, ssNew) {
  var resultObject = thObj
  var newSheet = ssNew.getActiveSheet();

  var currentSheetName = newSheet.getName();
  var currentFormulas = resultObject[currentSheetName];

  if (!currentFormulas) {
    // The current sheet name doesn't match any parameter in the object
    Logger.log("No match");
    return;
  }

  // Get the number of keys for the current parameter
  var numKeys = Object.keys(currentFormulas).length;
  if (numKeys == 0){
    Logger.log("The parameter does not have any thresholds");
    return;
  }
  // Insert new columns on the new sheet based on the number of keys
  newSheet.insertColumnsAfter(2, numKeys);
  newSheet.insertRowBefore(1);
  var currentRange = newSheet.getRange(1, 3, 1, numKeys);
  var currentKeys = Object.keys(currentFormulas);
  currentRange.setValues([currentKeys]);

  // Create an object to store placeholder references
  var placeholderReferences = placeholderObj;

  // Replace placeholders with cell references in the formulas
  var currentValues = currentRange.getValues()[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < currentKeys.length; i++) {
    var formula = currentFormulas[currentValues[i]].toString();

    // Replace placeholders in the formula with cell references
    for (var placeholder in placeholderReferences) {
      if (formula.indexOf(placeholder) !== -1) {
        formula = formula.replace(new RegExp(placeholder, 'g'), placeholderReferences[placeholder]);
      }
    }
    //newSheet.getRange(1,i+1).setValue(currentValues[i])
    newSheet.getRange(2, i + 3).setFormula(formula);
    var valuerange = newSheet.getRange(3, i+3, newSheet.getLastRow())
    newSheet.getRange(2,i+3).copyTo(valuerange);
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

[EDIT]
I did a workaround by using setValue instead of setFormula for the values that are static.
It aint pretty but it works.
Still would like to know why this happens and if I could have solved it in another way.

```
      var currentValues = currentRange.getValues()[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < currentKeys.length; i++) {
    var formula = currentFormulas[currentValues[i]].toString();
    let formvar = 0;
    // Replace placeholders in the formula with cell references
    for (var placeholder in placeholderReferences) {
      if (formula.indexOf(placeholder) !== -1) {
        formula = formula.replace(new RegExp(placeholder, 'g'), placeholderReferences[placeholder]);
        formvar++
      }
    }

    if(formvar == 0){
    formula=formula.replace(".", ",");
    newSheet.getRange(2, i + 3).setValue(formula);
    } else {
    newSheet.getRange(2, i + 3).setFormula(formula);
    }
    var valuerange = newSheet.getRange(3, i+3, newSheet.getLastRow()-2)
    newSheet.getRange(2,i + 3).copyTo(valuerange);
  }
```

Comment: too general please focus in on one question

Comment: @Cooper
I'm sorry but isnt it sort of one question? 
I want to know why it pastes a point instead of a comma and how I can avoid it in the future? 
I don't intend to sound dismissive but I don't know how to be more clear. Is it some specific part you found too general?

Comment: I don't think because you're asking the question in terms of your  application and we can't be knowledgeable about everyone's applications.  I would prefer answering questions about scripting.

Comment: Even if your Spreadsheet is set to the correct locale (to display the correct number formatting), it does not seem like this carries over to the Apps Script project. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298126/13771937), the most you can do is code the number as text, so that it doesn't get reformatted when it comes into GAS

Comment: Thank you Miguel, this does shed some more light on the issue. 
About locales, the way to set the default value for locale is in Google language settings, so if that doesnt carry over to GAS it sounds like a bug to me...